# Proving a tautology, notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

This may be a bit of a softball question, but I'm having difficulty understanding my math logic text. It says that $\{A, (A \rightarrow B)\} \vDash B$, which is statement I'm not sure how to prove. The part that trips me up is the notation (as you may have guessed from the question). Why is it that it's written with a comma, and how should I use truth tables to prove this? Generally I would create a truth table with $2^{n}$ number of T/F combinations, and then go on to prove that the end is simply all T. However, I'm not sure how to deal with the comma here. Again, sorry if this is an easy question, I'm new to logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the things delimited by commas are the $n$ columns of your truth table.

Eg

$$\begin{array}{cc}
A & B & A\to B \\
\hline
T & T & T \\
T & F & F \\
F & T & T\\
F & F & T
\end{array}
$$

and we notice that when $A$ and $A\to B$ are both true (the first row), then $B$ is also true.

Answer (score 3):

To explain the notation, $\{A,A\to B\}$ is a set of two propositions, $A$ and $A\to B,$ which are enclosed in brackets and separated by a comma as is customary when writing out sets in this notation.

What $\Gamma\vDash B $ ("$B$ is a logical consequence of $\Gamma$") means in propositional logic is that for every truth assignment to the variables in which all statements in $\Gamma$ are true, $B$ is true.

So to demonstrate $\{A,A\to B\}\vDash B,$ you must show that for every truth assignment in which $A$ and $A\to B$ are true, $B$ is true. (As is accomplished with the truth table in ziggurism's answer.)